# How can I get the last entry in a table with a specific ID

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 5 columns which are:

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------------+------+
| id | DeviceID | PossibleLeak | ConfirmedLeak | Time |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------+------+
```

and I want to select the last entry with a specific DeviceID. 
Is there a query I can use for that. 
Values are being inserted in there and the `id` column is auto-incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Filter your data on the specific `DeviceID`, order the data in descending order and get only the first record

```
select * 
from your_table
where DeviceID = 1234
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: thanks I was doing it a different way which didn't work